# AST for basic OOP language

Tags: oop, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

**In short :**

I'm trying to implement a subset of Ada language front end for educational purpose, but I'm stuck in basic OOP AST building.

**In details :**

I want to build a subset of Ada language front-end to use with LLVM system. My purpose is only for educational purpose not for a full functional, highly optimized compiler system.

My lexer/parser is built using Flex/Bison and I already have a grammar (based on Ada RM) to parse some code. Now I want to build an Abstract Syntax Tree for this grammar and finally write IR code to pass into LLVM system. (My questions are not related to write flex/bison rules and defining my grammar, I know how to do it).

I already know how to handle arithmetic expressions and function declaration,definition and calling, but I can't find helpful information about AST structure for OOP handling.

My questions are :

- How do you handle structure/class fields ? Is it a sum of single variables (in that case how names are handled, a mangling like C++ ?)
- How function members are handled ? (scope and accessibility)
- Are there good reference (link, article, book, ...) about handling/building of AST for OOP language(s) (I only find some links about writing AST using OOP language but it's useless) ?

I have a more advanced question about how generic are processed. I don't know how they are declared and used, any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance !